# Check value from two different dictionary with matched key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two dictionary with different keys but each key in dictionary is matched like job matches JobType, position matches PositionName, etc and I will like to compare if datadict value equals to exp value. I have following code and result is correct.
However, what is the better way for me to do it?

```
res = {}
exp = dict(
    job=['engineer', 'PM', 'teacher'],
    position=['officer', 'CEO', 'CFO'],
    name=['bob', ['John', 'amy']]
)
datadict = dict(JobType='teacher', PositionName='CEO', Name='a')
datadict2 = dict(JobType='teacher', PositionName='CEO', Name='x')
for j, v in zip(['job', 'position', 'name'], ['JobType', 'PositionName', 'Name']):
    res[j] = datadict[v]

for e, r in zip(sorted(exp), sorted(res)):
    if r == 'name':
        print(any(res[r] in s for s in exp[e][1]))
    else:
        print(res[r] in exp[e])

# result from datadict: True, True, True
# result from datadict2: True, False, True
```

Comment: Why are the key names different? Do they need to be? What's up with the structure of `exp['name']`? Does it have to be this way?

Comment: yes, that is why I build a res dictionary since I do not know a better way to do it

Comment: key **name** is one of example from my data that need to check. because its value may contain string and list

Comment: So the list in the `name` field happens if you have e.g. two teacher CEO's, one named John and one named amy? Or what does that actually represent?

Comment: Also, does it ever happen that `e` and `r` are not the same in your final `for` loop?

Comment: **name** field always exist, however, it can contains string on index 0, list on index 1. and since i rebuild res dictionary, i do not think e, r may have the situation with different value